# How to test a Facebook app from a virtual machine

Tags: facebook

Can anyone tell me what settings I need in a facebook app if I want to test my Graph calls directly from a virtual machine running on my laptop.

If I have the virtual machine on IP 1.2.3.4 and I have a virtualhost test.com configured on that VM.

I have test.com resolving to 1.2.3.4 in /etc/hosts on the laptop.

I can access the VM by entering test.com into the browser on my laptop but how can I get my facebook app to allow graph calls from the VM and be able to respond to it? It's a nightmare having to upload to my online server after every change!

I tried entering http://test.com and test.com as the configs but I still get no response from the app.

I created an access token from the developer tools and did the following sdk calls but got no response (the factory initialises the facebook object with the appID and secret - this code works on an online server):

```
$fb = Facebook_Factory::getFB();
    $fb->setAccessToken("access_token");
    print_r($fb->api("me/accounts"));
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this worked perfectly. I had a typo in my graph call #embarassing! At least this may be of use to someone else testing in a similar environment.